# django tastypie 401 Unauthorized

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I cant get this to work for the life of me.

I have this in api.py

```
class catResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = categories.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'categories'
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
    authentication = Authentication()
```

So when i try:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"name":"Test", "parent": "0", "sort": "1","username":"admin","password":"password"}' http://192.168.1.109:8000/api/v1/categories/
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.0 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Date: Sat, 21 Sep 2013 10:26:00 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.6.5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The model:

```
class categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True,null=True)
    sort = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.parent:
            prefix = str(self.parent)
        else:
            return self.name
        return ' > '.join((prefix,self.name))

    @classmethod
    def re_sort(cls):
        cats = sorted([ (x.__unicode__(),x) for x in cls.objects.all() ])
        for i in range(len(cats)):
            full_name,cat = cats[i]
            cat.sort = i 
            super(categories,cat).save()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(categories, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.re_sort()

    class Admin:
        pass
```

Comment: Well, the [documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) says that you need some sort of authentication for POST requests ... (look after "401")

Comment: `allowed_methods` and `authentication` should be inside `Meta`.

Comment: Arent they inside the meta?

Comment: Your code as listed in the question shows `allowed_methods` etc *outside* of `Meta`, but rather in `catResource`.

Answer (score 7):

Get your indents right (as was said in the comments) but you also need change the Authorization. By default Tastypie uses `ReadOnlyAuthorization` which will not allow you to POST.

https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html

```
class catResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = categories.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'categories'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization() # THIS IS IMPORTANT
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you that worked

```
class WordResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Word.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'word'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put']
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
```

mY model was like this

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    meaning = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    phrase = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    sentence = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    image_url = models.TextField(max_length=2000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

And don't forget

```
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
```

Comment: thumbs up for the "import" part